# Moodle and Drupal 7 integration

Tags: drupal, moodle

I would like to display a list of available Moodle courses and available places for each of the corses on a Drupal site.

Is there a simple way of integrating Moodle and Drupal so that when a Max enrolled users is set in Moodle, the Drupal enrolment form witll display the number of available places, and disable the ability of users enrolling in to courses which have no places left?

Answer (score 1):

There is authentication plugin available **moodle-drupalservices** for SSO between both systems 
You can read more about it from [module document](https://github.com/cannod/moodle-drupalservices/wiki/Installation-Moodle-Side)

If you want to fetch detail of moodle courses in drupal then web service is the best way to achieve it, you just need to create web services client in drupal to consume moodle services

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Category:Web_Services

use **core_course_get_courses** web service function don't need to pass any value to it, it will fetch all available courses detail from moodle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for moodle integration in drupal - [Moodle Connector](https://drupal.org/project/moodle_connector). There are some other related module to which enhance the integration further like [Commerce Moodle](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_moodle), which let you sell the course & you get drupal commerce to handle your selling..great right?

But if you are working in D6, then you will have to check another module [Moodleconnect](https://drupal.org/project/moodleconnect), but it's still in DEV version, so may be you will have to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/moodle_views will allow you to list courses using a Drupal View. This module doesn't (yet) allow you to display the places available, but if you still need this functionality I could probably add it relatively easily.